# Does square summability need to hold for every vector in an LVS?

Tags: vector-spaces, cauchy-sequences

In a Linear Vector space I can have an infinite number of vectors, given that I have an orthonormal basis set. If the LVS has infinite dimensionality then, I learnt that it needs to be square summable. So if I take a vector $V(x_{1}, x_{2},...)$ in this LVS and calculate the inner product as:

$Σ|x_{i}|^2 < ∞$

Does this hold true for ANY vector in the LVS? I could possibly give example that this sequence is convergent for certain vectors whilst divergent for others. Will it still be called an $ℓ^{2}$?

Comment: If $(e_i)$ is orthonormal and $x$ is any vecor then $\sum |x_i|^{2} <\infty$ where $x_i$ is defined as $ \langle x, e_i \rangle$. In fact $\sum |x_i|^{2}  \leq \|x\|^{2}$.

Comment: This relation must hold true for all vectors in an LVS?

Comment: Yes, it is true for all vectors provided the numbers $x_i$ are defined in terms of the basis $(e_i)$ as I mentioned in the previous comment.

Comment: Ah, thank you so much.